# How do I analyze a frozen linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, manjaro, freeze

I wonder how I can analyze/find any hint of why my Linux system freezes sometimes.

1. there are no logs in journald
2. REISUB doesn't work while frozen. I enabled it so normally it does.
3. there are no dumps from the freeze in `/var/lib/systemd/coredump/`

I'm using a whiskey-lake intel CPU, intel GPU and an untainted `5.10.15-1-MANJARO` kernel.

I have no idea where I can start looking for any clue why my system freezes. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this happening during busy time, or in times where your system would go into some kind of sleep mode?

Comment: the last 2 times it happened while I was watching videos in Kodi. Yet, it's not deterministic, so it might happen after 30min or 4 hours.

Comment: Might be a hardware bug, too. Try running memtest - does it crash there, too?

Comment: no, memtest runs fine 24h. I'm also affected by kernel bug (https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=211323), but this freezing happens in Kodi and doesn't leave any logs. I'll try to enable sync for syslog tomorrow and hope something shows up

Comment: Memtest is not a reliable test since you must at the very very least run it for 48 hours, but even repeated booting/rebooting sequences are harsher. You should use `mprime` (it's just the same famous Prime95 tool to harshly validate overclockings, but CLI only and made by the same guys) with the following settings : https://old.reddit.com/r/overclocking/comments/6dk5qn/prime95_what_fft_sizes_to_test_for_ram_stability/di3aw3a/

Comment: Do also check if your disks are not failling or do have any bad sectors. On servers and even workstations, one bad sector means the drive is good for the trash or repurposing. It also may be a swap-related or SSD issue (faulty drive sector, too much I/O on it, dying SSD because of wear-levelling having no more over-provisionned cells despite showing "0" bad sectors, etc)

Comment: Since you're on a laptop, did you check that the temperatures are fine ? Since almost all laptops are ultrabooks since around 2015, OEMs "thinks" that 90C-95C is perfertly normal while it's only not that far for TJunction. And the hotter things are, the less they (mainly the solders) will last long, medium or even short (that happened) term. The best maximum temperature to be keep under by most PC components is as a rule of thumb 70C (CPU, GPU, VRMs mostly), 50C (RAM, chipsets, case, capacitors, small chips) and 40C (drives, batteries). Your laptop may freeze because it's simply too hot.

Comment: @X.LINK thank you for suggesting mprime. I'm currently facing another kernel bug, which prevents me from using Prime95 for stability testing. It happened 2x while I was watching a movie from my local disk. I'd assume my laptop w/ 16 GB mem won't swap here and an SSD error while watching a movie shouldn't crash my OS. Temps are < 66°C when using prime for 2h.

Comment: Then your kernel may be the culprit after all, or your distribution if the drivers aren't 100% finished for your hardware, try to fix them first.
Forgot to tell, but the mentionned temps are the maximum ones to be reached during a very intense stress test in a 40C room.
If you suspect I/O issues, you shoud check them with `iotop` to see if something thrashes or suddently drops. If you do use Copy On Write filesystems (btrfs, ZFS which can hogs a lot of RAM, etc) then you'll have to check that too.
Another suspect would be the power supply/cord or your wall plugs, but that's very unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult one.

I would do the following:

1. enable frequent time-stamping in your syslog
2. mount your syslog with synchronous mount-options (sync)

Perhaps you can see when this is happening, and what is logged just before that.